# Spring JPA Property expressions find by intersection of items in a list

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

How can I write a JPA repository method with property expressions that check for the existence of multiple items, or properties on those items, in a list? I can lookup a single item in the list, see zip code below, but I'm trying to write a way to check for multiple zip codes, where each Person in the result set has both zip codes in their list of addresses.

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
    // Works
    Set<Person> findAllByAddresses_ZipCode(String zip);

    // Doesn't work - does not return expected results
    Set<Person> findAllByAddresses_ZipCode_And_Addresses_ZipCode(String zip1, String zip2);
}
```

My current hack is to fetch two sets for 2 zip codes, then find the intersection of the two sets:

```
public @ResponseBody
    Iterable<Person> personsWithBothZipCodes(@PathVariable("zip1") String zip1,
                                             @PathVariable("zip2") String zip2) {

    Set<Person> a = personRepository.findAllByAddresses_ZipCode(zip1);
    Set<Person> b = personRepository.findAllByAddresses_ZipCode(zip2);

    // Only return results that contain both zip1 and zip2.
    a.retainAll(b);

    return a;
}
```

The entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Person
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    // zipcode is a String property on an Address.
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = com.data.Address.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to write this as part of the method header? [Relevant docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation)

Comment: Can you show your entity?

Comment: Would you like to solve this with `spring-data` magic at all costs? I don't see its benefit over an old-school query.

Comment: @RandallFlagg Added a snippet from the entity.

Comment: @BalázsMáriaNémeth If at all possible. I am trying to solve for nth number of variables to check against. My repositories and controllers are getting auto-generated using Javapoet. Trying to solve with as little code as I can.

Comment: @Gaʀʀʏ if it is a pet project, then fine but otherwise I cannot see how it remains maintainable if it's so hard to find the solution for this trivial problem.

Comment: have you considered using @Query annotation inside the interface PersonRepository ?

Comment: I think this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47527594/spring-jparepository-findby-incollection-returns-union-not-intersection

Comment: @nabeel Using @Query would work. I previously solved it with `nativeQuery=true`, but I'm looking for a solution via keywords in the method name.

Comment: clear, but @Query lets use HQL, you don't need to use native query

Comment: I believe the method should be like this `personRepository.findAllByAddresses_ZipCodeInAndAddresses_ZipCodeIn(zipSet1, zipSet2)`

Comment: @pvpkiran It looks good on paper, but after examining the generated query, it is doing the check on the same object: `... where (address2_.zipcode in (?)) and (address2_.zipcode in (?))`. It is doing a left join on Address. I don't think it is possible with keywords. Query might be the way to go here, as nabeel suggested.

Comment: ya you are right, i just tested that. Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48424575/how-to-search-through-array-in-spring-boot-crudrepository/48425205#48425205. I think you can extend that

Comment: Not as nice as I'd like, but I managed to solve it with @Query by comparing the size of matching zip codes:
`@Query("select p from Person p where :size = (select count(addr.zip) from p.addresses addr where addr.zipcode in :zip)")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes just add the word `In` to your query

```
Set<Person> findAllByAddresses_ZipCodeIn(Set<String> zip);
```

Then in your controller you can do something like:

```
public @ResponseBody Iterable<Person> personsWithBothZipCodes(@PathVariable("zip1") String zip1, @PathVariable("zip2") String zip2) {

    Set<String> zipSet = new HashSet<>();
    zipSet.add(zip1);
    zipSet.add(zip2);

    Set<Person> a = personRepository.findAllByAddresses_ZipCodeIn(zipSet);

    return a;
}
```

Dont know if this will work but can try

```
Set<Person> findAllByAddresses_ZipCodeInAndZipCodeIn(Set<String> zip1, Set<String> zip2);

public @ResponseBody Iterable<Person> personsWithBothZipCodes(@PathVariable("zip1") String zip1, @PathVariable("zip2") String zip2) {

    Set<String> zipSet1 = new HashSet<>();
    zipSet1.add(zip1);

    Set<String> zipSet2 = new HashSet<>();
    zipSet2.add(zip2);

    Set<Person> a = personRepository.findAllByAddresses_ZipCodeInAndZipCodeIn(zipSet1, zipSet2);

    return a;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't quite solve my issue. I want to fetch Persons that have all of the given zips, not just one in the list, hence my intersection set in the controller. Clarified the question.

Comment: See my edit. I dont know if itll work but can trying addin another in so it would be `InAndIn`

Comment: `findAllByAddresses_ZipCodeInAndIn` doesn't quite work, I think the closest to that is `findAllByAddresses_ZipCodeInAndZipCodeIn`, but it is asserting the same address zip code is in both input parameters. Not quite the solution I need. I think I may have to stick with my initial hack, but thank you for sharing your ideas. I was unaware of the "in" keyword.

Comment: Maybe `Person` needs to be joined to `Address` twice. So that a result set returns tuples like person, address1.zip, address2.zip. That might be tricky to solve with spring magic.

Comment: @Gaʀʀʏ double check you are setting your sets right. It shouldn't be inserting the same zip code if you have two distinct sets past in. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use JPQL query (as suggested in comments)?

```
@Query("from Person as person" +
" join person.addresses as address1 with address1.zipCode = ?1" +
" join person.addresses as address2 with address2.zipCode = ?2")
Set<Person> findByZipCodes(String zipCode1, String zipCode2);
```

Haven't really reproduced your case, but it should probably work.

Comment: This would work. I didn't mention in the question, but I was trying to achieve a solution for an unlimited number of zip codes. Here's the final solution I went with: `@Query("select p from Person p where :size = (select count(addr.zip) from p.addresses addr where addr.zipcode in :zip)")`, where `:size` represents the size of the List of zip codes `:zip`.